# Remove from array if nothing behind in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I'm working on an online booking system and currently use a table bookings (id, slot id, treatment, user, date), treatments (id, name, description, duration), timeslots(id, time).
In the first page of booking you see treatment options, and a calender datepicker. Once you pick the calender date it sends this off to a php page and returns a list of available timeslot.

In this php page I have an array of booked times, an array of all the slots. The booked times are substracted from all available slots and the remaining array(all available slots) is then shown to the user so they see all times they can book an appointment.

Now I want to add a duration variable into the mix. This means that array of booked timeslots (say 3,5) and available timeslots(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) if the duration is bigger than two, the result of taking the first array off the second is (6,7,8,9,10). if the duration is 2, (1,2,6,7,8,9,10) and if it is 1 (1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10). Does anyone know how I can do such a thing?

Just for help with suggestions this is the php page:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $treatment = $_POST['treatment'];
$bookdate = $_POST['bookdate'];

if(!isset($treatment) && isset($bookdate)){

$else = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SLOTS");
echo '<SELECT>';
while($array_else = mysql_fetch_array($else)){
echo "<OPTION value=".$array_else['SL_ID'].">".$array_else['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</SELECT>";
}else{

    $exp = explode("-", $bookdate);
    //determine what day of the week it is
    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$exp[1],$exp[0],$exp[2]);
    $dw = date( "w", $timestamp); // sun0,mon1,tue2,wed3,thur4,fri5,sat6

    //find bookings with same date
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT BOOK_SLOT_ID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE BOOK_DATE='$bookdate'");
    //make array of booking slots
    $array1 = array();
    while ($s1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $array1[] = $s1['BOOK_SLOT_ID'];
    }
    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT SL_ID FROM SLOTS");
    //make array of all slots
    $array2 = array();
    while ($s2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $array2[] =  $s2['SL_ID'];
    }
        if($dw == 6){
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT SL_ID FROM SLOTS ORDER BY SL_ID DESC LIMIT 4");
        $array = array();
        while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $array[] = $s['SL_ID'];}
        $array_res_merge = array_merge((array)$array1,(array)$array);
        $arr_res = array_diff($array2, $array_res_merge);
        }elseif($dw != 6){
        //remove bookings from all slots
        $arr_res = array_diff($array2, $array1);
        }
    echo '<div>';
    //make selectable options of results
    echo '<SELECT id="timeslots">';
    foreach($arr_res as $op){
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT SL_TIME FROM SLOTS WHERE SL_ID='$op'");
    $q3 = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    echo "<OPTION value=".$op.">".$q3['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
    }
    echo '</SELECT>';
    echo'</div>';
}

?>
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't if the duration is 2, = (1,2,7,8,9,10) instead?

Comment: Ah, that would be if slot 5 had a duration of 2 also, but I planned on solving that by just adding an extra record for 6 if that was the case.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry for using apparently outdated ways of writing this. I just want to have it all working first in the way I understand doing it and after that I'll be sure to take your advice and change it according to what these articles teach me. Thanks for helping me learn how to do things correctly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point out that improving the description of your variables by giving better names would help read the code. I will point out the logic since it would take a while to figure out your variables...

```
$my_slots_id = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$my_bookings = array(array("id"=>2,"duration"=>2),array("id"=>5,"duration"=>1));
foreach($my_bookings as $booking){
    array_splice($my_slots_id,array_search($booking["id"],$my_slots_id),$booking["duration"]);
}
```

Use array_slice to do the remove from the array. First param is the array, second param is the start key, and third param is the interesting one: it defines how many to take off.

To remove the items starting at the id and going backward, simply do this:

```
array_splice($my_slots_id,array_search($booking["id"],$my_slots_id)-$booking["duration"],$booking["duration"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I'm currently figguering out this function. Since I want to count backwards I think it's best to just use array reverse before using this, and then reversing the outcome again. So far it looks like this probably solves my issue, many thanks!

Comment: No, its a small array so wouldn't be dramatic but big arrays would destroy performance. I have edited my answer to show you how to do it easily.

Comment: Thanks for being so involved it is much appreciated! I almost have what I want, except if I have duration 2 for values 6 and 7 I outputs 5 6 4 7.. I understand why it does this, but I want it to fix so it will give me 5 6 6 7 because in my goal it has nothing to do with 4.. Do you know how this can be achieved? I'd be forever grateful. :)

Comment: Ah then you are not trying to remove but to grab... Use array_slice instead of array_splice.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I wouldn't have managed without it!